# Apache .htaccess - 301 redirecting home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect website A to website B. All of the sub-pages are redirecting as intended, but the home page is not. Here is a snippet of my .htaccess:

```
# HOMEPAGE  (This one isn't working)
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.drinkinggamezone.com [L,R=301]

# SUBPAGE (Works)
RewriteRule ^1990s-rock-power-hour/?$ http://drinkinggamezone.com/power-hours/1990s-rock? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Does `RewriteRule ^$ http://www.drinkinggamezone.com [L,R=301]` (without the `/` in the first part) work ?

Comment: Trying this resulted in the following "406 Not Acceptable" error:

`Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource / could not be found on this server.`

Comment: Wow, never had this error before. From what I've found via a quick Google search, this seems to be related to `mod_security`.

Comment: Yeah I think that error is related to the new website, not your code that I placed on the old website. I will try to find a fix for it - thanks.

Comment: @roberto06 Your suggestion works! and I believe the 406 error went away (fixed itself? idk)

Comment: @roberto06 do you know how i can expand it to also redirect if "inedx.php" is specified in the URL?

Comment: I added an answer including a rule for `index.php` (assuming `inedx` is a typo), hope it helps.

Comment: This is so weird. after i uploaded that line to the site I want to redirect, it hits the new site and results in: `Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

*Nevermind I had a typo in the .htaccess*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unnecessary `/` in the first part of your rule, it should be :

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.drinkinggamezone.com [L,R=301]
```

Regarding `index.php`, just do the same (again, without `/`, obviously) :

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.drinkinggamezone.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This was the all-encompassing answer I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://DomainB.com/$1 [P]
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: I tried this but it was yielding a 404 error on the website that I was trying to redirect's home page.